# Linux file command

Tags: linux, encoding

I have noticed that Linux `file` command does not return any value if an xml file has the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the top. If the prolog is missing then `file -i somefile.xml` returns some value. Does anyone has any idea why this happens? I am basically interested in knowing the file encoding and have found `file -i filename.xml` to be somewhat useful, but is there anything better available on Linux to figure the encoding and charset?

Answer (score 2):

File relies on the [signature in the magic file](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html), it is quite certain that it is looking at the prolog only, not scanning parts of the file to keep it simple.

Comment: That is what I wondering that maybe it just looks at the prolog which isn't really helpful because I can encode the file in X and write Y in the prolog

Answer (score 1):

Guessing encodings is a black art that even popular browsers can't get exactly right. I suggest you let your parser obey the XML encoding, breaking loudly if the encoding turns out to be invalid, and that you fix encoding mistakes at the source.